# Missing network protocols? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

Not sure where else to turn for this one. Recently, after updating my OS, I frequently run into an issue that is preventing me from using WiFi at all. When I run the Network Toubleshooter, I get two errors:

"One or more Network Protocols are missing on this computer"

And

"Winsock registry entries required for network connectivity are missing"

Last time I got this error, a couple days ago, I used netsh Winsock reset in cmd to reset Winsock and I turned off my antivirus protection (set to turn back on upon system restart), which fixed the issue temporarily. I also tried running sfc /scannow to fix any problems but it came up empty.

Also, I even stole my brothers WinSock and Winsock2 registries and attempted to manually install them via regedit (his computer is brand new, works beautifully). Even this did not solve my problem.

Although the netsh reset was temporary, I would like to know of a permanent fix to this issue, and I'd prefer not to have to go to a restore point. Also, I uninstalled my antivirus, still having problems. Let me know!

Comment: Try running these commands from an elevated command prompt and press `Enter` for each in this order, and then reboot the machine and see if it resolves for long term. Let me know if so and I'll add as an answer for you to accept: `nbtstat -RR`, `netsh advfirewall reset`, `netsh int ip reset`, `netsh int ipv6 reset`, and lastly `netsh winsock reset`. Now restart your PC and see if the problem comes back after the usual amount of time it has for you otherwise.